# I need help finding a mimic

Tags: terraria-console

I can't find a mimic in terraria for the life of me. Could some one help me? I only have adamite gear.

I also am playing on Xbox 360.

How and where can I get a mimic to spawn?

Answer (score 1):

First, go to the underworld, cling on to the ceiling while scanning for pearlstone; a pink stone resembling ebonstone or crimstone. Then, you must build a platform close to the surface out of full blocks. After that, build a mini arena near the full block platform. Eventually, a mimic will spawn on the full block platform and you should be able to kill it with a repeater and a good stack of hellfire arrows. And then you have a chance of getting the thing you want (which if I had to guess is the Daedulus Stormbow).
This is for the hallowed mimic, for the others just do the same with the biomes changed.

Answer (score 0):

I play on PC, I used to play on the Wii U 2016-2019+

The Mimics are spawned in the cavern of any underground biome you have the right armour for this fake chest monster. They are like slimes because they jump rapidly towards you. What I recommend is to stay away from it and shoot a ranged weapon because they are very strong.

Answer (score 0):

Mimics can appear both as induced or natural spawns.

In order to get mimics to spawn naturally, you must first unlock hardmode by beating the wall of flesh.

These are the mimics currently in the game, with their respective biomes, or the locations they can naturally appear in as random spawns:

```
+-----------+---------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| Type      | Biomes                          | Spawnrate | Manual method |
+-----------+---------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| Regular   | Underground, Cavern, Underworld | Uncommon  | Statue        |
| Ice       | Ice                             | Uncommon  | None          |
| Hallowed  | Underground Hallow              | Rare      | Key           |
| Corrupt   | Underground Corruption          | Rare      | Key           |
| Crimson   | Underground Crimson             | Rare      | Key           |
+-----------+---------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Underground here means below the dirt layer on top of the world. You can notice the biome transition by the changing background music.

---

**Creating Mimics**

A **regular** mimic can be created by wiring up and activating a *chest statue* anywhere. These will not drop loot if killed. Note that these can be created even without unlocking hardmode, as all the components are available before it.

One of the three elite: *hallowed*, *corrupt*, or *crimson* mimics can be manually created by:

- finding a chest in its respective biome, and
- using a *Key of light*, or *Key of night* on it. Both keys can be crafted at your workbench by using 15 *Souls of light* (or night, for the other version) after unlocking hardmode. The souls drop from the various monsters in the new Hallowed and Crimson biomes.

Mimics created this way do drop loot.

---

Read more about mimics using the [Wiki page on mimics](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Mimics).